# Given an image, create the plot exactly as it is shown to the best of your ability

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to graph that kinda looks like it is exponentially decreasing (see picture), but I can't seem to get it to work...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p0 = 1013.
Rd = 0.2871
g = 0.00981
T = T0 = 288.
y = 0.000006
H = (Rd*T)/g
z = np.arange(0.,1600.,)
yz = y*z
yR = y*Rd

p1 = (p0)*(np.exp(-z/H))

p2 = (p0)*(((T-yz)/T)**(g/yR))


plt.plot(p1,z,'g-')
plt.plot(p2,z,'r--')

plt.legend(['Isothermal', 'Constant γ'])
plt.title('Pressure (mb) vs. Altitude (km) --  Brandi Slavich')
plt.xlabel("Pressure (mb)")
plt.ylabel('Altitude (km)')
plt.grid(linestyle='--')
plt.axis([100.,1000.,0.,16.])
plt.show()


TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
---> p1 = (p0)*(exp(-z/H))
```

Goal image:

[image: GOAL IMAGE]

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: `p1 = (p0)*(exp(-z/H))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from `exp(-z/H)`. To avoid this, you may use `np.exp` instead.

It looks like `math.exp` can only handle scalar or a `numpy.ndarray` with shape (1, ).

```
import numpy as np
import math

math.exp(np.array([100]))
# 2.6881171418161356e+43

math.exp(np.array([100, 200]))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

np.exp(np.array([100, 200]))
# array([  2.68811714e+43,   7.22597377e+86])
```

---

**Added:**

Also, I think the axis range of your plot `[100.,1000.,0.,16.]` doesn't fit the range of your data (`z`, `p1`, `p2`) well.

```
# y-axis: 0 - 16
# >>> (z.min(), z.max())
# (0.0, 1599.0) 

# x-axis: 100 - 1000
# >>> (p1.min(), p1.max())
# (837.95200017838602, 1013.0)
# >>> (p2.min(), p2.max())
# (835.24824032186791, 1013.0)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `np.array()` and `np.arange()`? Because I can't get my lines to curve exponentially now and I feel like that may be the problem

Comment: @Brandi [`np.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) create an ndarray. [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is like a `numpy` version of `range()`, which creates a sequence (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ...) in ndarray form. And I think other parameters may affect the shape of your curves and make them less 'exponentially'-looking.